# How to insert background image in jquery?

Tags: jquery, html

I need help, this is my code and I searched alot but i could not find any thing works for me. Where can I put the jquery code? and which one it will work for me?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

    <head>

        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="jquery.mobile-1.4.5.css">
        <script src="jquery-1.12.0.min.js"></script>
        <script src="jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>


    </head>


    <body>



        <div data-role="page" id="home"  >
            <div id="header">
                <h1 align="center";><font color="white">Member Login</font></h1>

            </div>
            <form>
                <input type="text" placeholder="Username">

                <input type="text" placeholder="Health Card Number">
                <input id="rememberme" type="checkbox">
                <label for="rememberme">Remember</label>
                <input type="submit" value="Login Now">
            </form>
</div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Where do you wants to add the background?

Comment: @hmd 
 
I want to add the Background to the page " loging page"

Answer (score 0):

Try it:

```
<script>
        $("document").ready(function(){
           $("#home").css("background-image","url('http://cache1.asset-cache.net/gc/519249945-hexagon-abstract-background-gettyimages.jpg?v=1&c=IWSAsset&k=2&d=LBXRX%2BPPwv%2BPvsKWANsuTH1c3dDbAxUoJxxrmsO0Fpr0Z7%2BFa7zjX%2F4eaCS3h%2B2h')");
        });
    </script>
```

See demo here: [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/fcrxG1hROltJD6dTRipH?p=preview)